# Build.Gradle : Cannot access zzbej

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am facing one issue while integrating the Admob library.

> error: cannot access zzbej
>
> class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej not found

I got an error while adding the Admob library to build.gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not to be rude, but if you google your error `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej not found` then you can find it. Solution: make sure the version number of dependent libraries are consistent.